# Another way to cancel Task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple console application

```
class Program
{
    private static void MyTask(object obj)
    {
        var cancellationToken = (CancellationToken) obj;
        if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("MyTask() started");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }


            Console.WriteLine($"Counter in MyTask() = {i}");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("MyTask() finished");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(MyTask, cancelationTokenSource.Token,
            cancelationTokenSource.Token);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        try
        {
            cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if(task.IsCanceled)
                Console.WriteLine("Task has been cancelled");

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cancelationTokenSource.Dispose();
            task.Dispose();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start new Task and after some time cancel it. Is there any other way to achieve this result instead of using this

```
if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

on every iteration in for loop? Why do we have to check cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested on every iteration, maybe we can to use  something else?

Comment: That's how it is done. When you have a long task p, that's the way it's implemented to allow for interruption.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov it is pretty silly that we have to check evey single time if task is cancelled

Comment: It's bare bones how it would've been done even in the assembler - a variable that is controlled outside the loop - what did you expect?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)`, as `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` [already handles that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx). But yes, you need to add these calls at "safe" checkpoints in your long-running task, as there's no way for the compiler/runtime to know when it is "safe" to stop your task otherwise.

Comment: There are lots of ways to cancel a task, and there are lots of Q&As on Stack Overflow discussing some of these various ways. In almost all cases, they involve some synchronized interaction between the cancelling and cancelled thread allowing the cancelled thread to know that it's being cancelled and to interrupt itself gracefully. Asking "is there any other way" is simply far too broad.

Comment: "it is pretty silly" why?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you could avoid the [`.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx), and instead simply use a `break` to stop the execution of the loop and then finish the `Task`. The `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is more useful in deeper task trees, where there are many more descendants and it is more difficult to maintain cancellation.

```
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    break;
}
```

Stephen Toub has a [good explanation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45/taskfactorystartnew-cancellation-token-parameter?forum=parallelextensions) on how the throwing of the OCE is more of an acknowledgement.

> If the body of the task is also monitoring the cancellation token and throws an `OperationCanceledException` containing that token (which is what `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` does), then when the task sees that OCE, it checks whether the OCE's token matches the Task's token.  If it does, that exception is viewed as an acknowledgement of cooperative cancellation and the Task transitions to the Canceled state (rather than the Faulted state).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your objection to checking on every iteration is, but if you do not want to check on every iteration, for whatever reason, check the value of `i`:

E.g. this checks every 10th loop:

```
if (i % 10 == 0 && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
```

The reason you must check is so that you can decide where is best to stop the task so that work is not left in an inconsistent state. Here though all you will achieve by checking less frequently is a task that is slower to cancel, maybe that will lead to a less responsive UX. E.g. where the task would end in 500ms before, now it can take up to 10x that, 5 secs.

However if each loop was very fast, and checking the flag every loop proves to significantly increase the overall time the task takes, then checking every `n` loops makes sence.